# @RestController removes spaces in string

Tags: spring

I have found an interesting bug/feature while writing webservice. I am returning JSON data for selection filter in frontend. Then these selections are returned me back to get data. I am sending it to a database so I need exactly the same format.

Problem is when there are more then two spaces in its name. On JSON output it removes any number of spaces and leaves only one. But I need all of them. How can I force RestController to leave there all spaces?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FilterController {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FilterController.class);

    @Autowired
    SentimentService sentimentService; 

    @RequestMapping(value="/filter", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Filter getValues(@RequestParam(value="sources", defaultValue="50") int sourceNb) {
        Filter filter = sentimentService.filterGetValue();
        return filter;
    }
}
```

This is my controller. Filter is object with tree structure. One of them is Product layer. I even added sysout there. The spaces are saved in the object but not passed to JSON output.

```
public class Product {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name); // it really has two spaces there
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

Is there any annotation I need to add to my class variable to be left as it is? I couldn't find anything useful so I just hope that it can be done easily. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is what is happening? Jackson/spring shouldn't be altering the value of a `String`. It seems more likely the error lies in your code/DB somewhere.

Comment: I add to getter sysout. I call the webservice and the sysout is called when creating json. In console it has two spaces, in browser it does not. There isn't any code between...

Comment: but you made me think... my browser does that. If I save it to file there are actually two spaces... So thanks. And sorry for bad question

Comment: Try using an add-on like [jsonview](http://jsonview.com/) to view the actual json contents. Cheers.